# How to make PNG (8-bit Indexed Colors) using buffers? Getting "compression header fails checksum"

Tags: buffer, png, zlib, gml, game-maker-studio-2

how are you?

I'm trying to make a PNG from scratch on Game Maker Studio 2 using Buffers, but I'm getting some errors using pngcheck:

```
File: [01;37mtest.png[0m (85 bytes)
  chunk [40;33mIHDR[0m at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    2 x 2 image, 8-bit palette, non-interlaced
  chunk [40;33mPLTE[0m at offset 0x00025, length 12: 4 palette entries
  chunk [40;33mIDAT[0m at offset 0x0003d, length 4
    zlib: compression header fails checksum
    zlib: inflate error = -3 (data error)
```

I'm posting the code below to show what I got so far.
As you can see, I've managed to add the IHDR header, set the Bit Depth to 8, Color Type to 3 etc. and add all the other chunks of data.

I also managed to get the CRC field working by adding a CRC32 script in Game Maker to calculate the correct bytes.

What I'm trying to achieve is create a simple 2x2 image with 4 different colors using the colors from the PLTE chunk, but what I'm getting is a single red square (2x2) and also the errors above from pngcheck.

I think I'm missing the "compression" part of it, it would be very helpful if someone could help me with this.

```
// Variables
var File;

File = argument0;

// Loop Variables
var i;

// Create Buffer
var Buffer = buffer_create(1024, buffer_grow, 1);

// Signature
var Signature = [0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A];
for(i=0; i<8; i++){ buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, Signature[i]); }


// --------------------------------------------------
// IHDR
// --------------------------------------------------
// Length
var IHDRLength = 13;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IHDRLength >> 24) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IHDRLength >> 16) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IHDRLength >> 8) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IHDRLength & 255));

// CRC Position
var IHDRCRCPos = buffer_tell(Buffer);

// Type
var IHDRType = ["I", "H", "D", "R"];
for(i=0; i<4; i++){ buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, ord(IHDRType[i])); }

// Data (Bytes): Width (4), Height (4), Bit Depth (1), Color Type (1), Compression Method (1), Filter Method (1), Interlace Method (1)
// Width
var Width = 2;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (Width >> 24) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (Width >> 16) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (Width >> 8) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (Width & 255));

// Height
var Height = 2;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (Height >> 24) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (Height >> 16) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (Height >> 8) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (Height & 255));

// Bit Depth
var BitDepth = 8;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, BitDepth);

// Color Type
var ColorType = 3;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, ColorType);

// Compression
var Compression = 0;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, Compression);

// Filter
var Filter = 0;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, Filter);

// Interlace
var Interlace = 0;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, Interlace);

// CRC (Type+Data Bytes)
var IHDRCRC = CRC32(Buffer, IHDRCRCPos, 17);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IHDRCRC >> 24) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IHDRCRC >> 16) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IHDRCRC >> 8) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IHDRCRC & 255));


// --------------------------------------------------
// PLTE
// --------------------------------------------------
// Length (Colors*3)
var PLTELength = 4*3;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (PLTELength >> 24) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (PLTELength >> 16) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (PLTELength >> 8) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (PLTELength & 255));

// CRC Position
var PLTECRCPos = buffer_tell(Buffer);
var ColorBytes = 0;

// Type
var PLTEType = ["P", "L", "T", "E"];
for(i=0; i<4; i++){ buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, ord(PLTEType[i])); }

// Data (Bytes): R (1), G (1), B (1)
// PLTELength div Colors
// Color 1
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 55);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 55);
ColorBytes += 3;

// Color 2
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 55);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 55);
ColorBytes += 3;

// Color 3
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 55);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 55);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 255);
ColorBytes += 3;

// Color 4
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 0);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 0);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 0);
ColorBytes += 3;

// CRC
var PLTECRC = CRC32(Buffer, PLTECRCPos, 4+ColorBytes);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (PLTECRC >> 24) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (PLTECRC >> 16) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (PLTECRC >> 8) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (PLTECRC & 255));


// --------------------------------------------------
// IDAT
// --------------------------------------------------
// Length (Pixels*3)
var IDATLength = Width*Height;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IDATLength >> 24) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IDATLength >> 16) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IDATLength >> 8) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IDATLength & 255));

// CRC Position
var IDATCRCPos = buffer_tell(Buffer);
var IDATBytes = 0;

// Type
var IDATType = ["I", "D", "A", "T"];
for(i=0; i<4; i++){ buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, ord(IDATType[i])); }

// Data (Bytes): Color Index (1)
// Colors (Width > Height)
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 0);
IDATBytes += 1;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 1);
IDATBytes += 1;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 2);
IDATBytes += 1;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, 3);
IDATBytes += 1;

// CRC
var IDATCRC = CRC32(Buffer, IDATCRCPos, 4+IDATBytes);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IDATCRC >> 24) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IDATCRC >> 16) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IDATCRC >> 8) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IDATCRC & 255));


// --------------------------------------------------
// IEND
// --------------------------------------------------
// Length
var IENDLength = 0;
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IENDLength >> 24) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IENDLength >> 16) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IENDLength >> 8) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IENDLength & 255));

// CRC Position
var IENDCRCPos = buffer_tell(Buffer);

// Type
var IENDType = ["I", "E", "N", "D"];
for(i=0; i<4; i++){ buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, ord(IENDType[i])); }

// CRC
var IENDCRC = CRC32(Buffer, IENDCRCPos, 4);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IENDCRC >> 24) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IENDCRC >> 16) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IENDCRC >> 8) & 255);
buffer_write(Buffer, buffer_u8, (IENDCRC & 255));

// Save Buffer
buffer_save(Buffer, "test.png");

// Delete Buffers
buffer_delete(Buffer);
```

Thanks for your time!

## SOLUTION

EDIT: please look at the comment from Mark Adler for the solution, there was a nice discussion there and he helped me through all the process.

The reason why my PNG was not being created was:

1. It was missing a 1 byte value for each row in the data from the IDAT chunk, so it's 6 bytes of data instead of 4.

Like:

```
0 0 1
0 2 3
```

2. It was missing the zlib compression in the data from the IDAT chunk. If you're using Game Maker, do not use the buffer_compress function, instead, use the zlib extension made by YellowAfterlife [HERE](https://marketplace.yoyogames.com/assets/5428/zlib-compression-decompression).
3. When I compressed the data, it added 8 bytes to the buffer. These bytes needs to be taken into consideration when you're calculating the LENGTH and CRC values of the IDAT chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you are not implementing the required compression. Also each row must be prefixed by a filter byte, so you will compressing six bytes, not four.

The required compression for the IDAT chunks is the zlib format (a zlib header and trailer around deflate-compressed data). I do not know if or how zlib is made available in the environment you are programming in.

Using a filter type of zero (no filtering) for both rows, the data you will compress is the six bytes 0 0 1 0 2 3. Once you get it all right, the result will be, in hex:

```
89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52
00 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 08 03 00 00 00 45 68 fd
16 00 00 00 0c 50 4c 54 45 ff 37 37 37 ff 37 37
37 ff 00 00 00 5d 2a e4 7e 00 00 00 0e 49 44 41
54 78 9c 63 60 60 64 60 62 06 00 00 11 00 07 9e
a2 2a 12 00 00 00 00 49 45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82
```

Comment: Hi @Mark Adler, thanks for the answer. So, for each row I have to add 2 U8 values (2 bytes), correct? Since I'm using Color Type 3 (Indexed Color), shouldn't it be 3 bytes instead of 6? (2 for the filter, 1 for the color index?). Unfortunately I don't have access to the libraries in Game Maker, but there is a "buffer_compress" function that I need to take a look to see if it works first. [link](https://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/4_gml_reference/buffers/buffer_compress.html)

Comment: Also, when you say "compression for the IDAT chunks", are you referring to the whole chunk or just the pixel data? Do I have to apply a zlib compression to the entire IDAT chunk including the Length, Type, Data and CRC?

Comment: The IDAT chunk _data_ is a zlib steam. More correctly, if there are multiple IDAT chunks, the _concatenation_ of the IDATs chunk data is a single zlib stream. That data is not just pixels, but also a single filter byte at the start of each row.

Comment: There _one_ filter byte at the start of each row. For color type 3, each pixel is one byte, which is an index into the palette. So a 2x2 image would be six bytes.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said about adding 1 byte for the filter for each row and I also tried using the "buffer_compress" function provided by Game Maker but it didn't work, so I found an extension by YellowAfterlife on the Marketplace (zlib compression) and it seems like it worked! I compressed the data from IDAT (level 8). I can get pass the "compression header fails checksum" message, and now it says: "zlib: deflated, 32K window, maximum compression", so at this point can we assume that the compression worked? The problem is that now I'm getting a CRC error in the IDAT chunk :(

Comment: Btw, this is the log in checkpng:
`File: [01;37mtest.png[0m (123 bytes)
  chunk [40;33mIHDR[0m at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    2 x 2 image, 8-bit palette, non-interlaced
  chunk [40;33mPLTE[0m at offset 0x00025, length 12: 4 palette entries
  chunk [40;33mIDAT[0m at offset 0x0003d, length 13
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, maximum compression
  CRC error in chunk IDAT (computed d668a65c, expected ef6c8c7d)
[01;31mERRORS DETECTED[0m in test.png`

Comment: Compute the CRC on the "IDAT" + compressed data. Use the length of the compressed data for the chunk length.

Comment: Yes! I did everything you told me and now it's creating the 8-Bit PNG with indexed colors as expected, thank you very much! I just checked some of the docs and I saw your name in it, I didn't know you are one of the creators of the PNG format, what an honor! Lessons learned: don't forget the 1 byte filter in each row of data in IDAT, pay attention to the Length and calculate the CRC correctly (take the compression into the consideration), and if you're using Game Maker, use the ZLIB extension from YellowAfterlife to compress the IDAT data instead of using the "buffer_compress" function.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that GMS2 `buffer_compress` does call zlib `compress`, so should be good to use as long as you're aware of two header bytes and trailing 4 bytes of CRC32. I have used it in past to [generate ZIP files](https://github.com/YAL-GameMaker/zip-writer).